# org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.ClientConnectionException: Invalid response received on web3j on Android

Tags: solidity, remix, infura, web3j, android

I am trying to execute transactions by calling my RegisterNewUser function in the deployed smart contract through Android and I am using Infura. However, when I run, there is an error as seen below :

`org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.ClientConnectionException: Invalid response received: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@75f0732`

and I am not sure what this error means and how to solve it.

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3jFactory
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt
import org.web3j.protocol.infura.InfuraHttpService
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.util.concurrent.Future

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = javaClass.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val contractAddress = "0xcc7bbfe74095a18a77f178332e43bb29fec55d9a"
        val url = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/a5160b4fb30f49b48161ea7d6de80cf6"
        val web3j = Web3jFactory.build(InfuraHttpService(url))
        val gasLimit: BigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(3000000)
        val gasPrice: BigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(10000)
        val credentials = Credentials.create("MY_PRIVATE_KEY")

        val greeter = UserAccountFactory.load(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        button.setOnClickListener { _ ->
            val thread = Thread(Runnable {
                try {
                    val transactionReceipt1: Future<TransactionReceipt>? = greeter.registerNewUser("abc@mail.com","777888","Customer").sendAsync()
                    val result1 = "Successful transaction. Gas used: ${transactionReceipt1?.get()?.blockNumber}  ${transactionReceipt1?.get()?.gasUsed}"
                    Log.d(TAG, result1)

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Log.d(TAG, "error accessing contract: " + e.message)
                }
            })
            thread.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I have done wrong?

Comment: My suggestion is view the response and see if it gives you a clue

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, but what do I need to type in the code in order to view the response?

Comment: I am not Java programmer but this would fall under the generic skills of "how to view and debug HTTP traffic on Android"

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thank you for the reply.